# Can a .NET assembly be signed using an X509Certificate?

Tags: c#, security, code-signing, authenticode

I believe I have a foundational understanding of the X509Certificate and have created certificates and private keys for my Development environment. Getting more acquainted now with the X509Certificate Class and other relevant permissions also.

So in the process, I decided to test a certificate after having installed it on my system. Then using the following code, I attempted to validate the check process for certification authentication:

```
const string x509Cert = @"\PathToMyCertificate\LMC.cer";
var cert = new X509Certificate(x509Cert);
var pmc = new PublisherMembershipCondition(cert);
if(pmc.Check(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Evidence))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Assembly belongs to publisher");
}
```

Of course as expected, the inner block of code doesn't execute. So then I figured to simply sign my assembly using the certificate key, but "simply" wasn't as simple as I'd anticipated.

I used the following code in effort of assigning the certificate to my applications Evidence:

```
var publisher = new Publisher(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(x509Cert));
var evidence = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Evidence;
evidence.AddHost(publisher);

// Create an identity permission based on publisher evidence.
var x509Permission = (PublisherIdentityPermission)publisher.CreateIdentityPermission(evidence);
x509Permission.Demand();
```

But this didn't seem to work either. Next, I checked the properties of my project to see if there was any way to sign it there using the X509Certificate key but nothing. The only option I see that comes close is to sign with Click Once manifests; but the "Select from file" option is looking for a .pfx extension. So I think maybe this method only works to support certificates generated by Click-Once?

Per BOL, "If you have a key file or certificate in another format, store it in the Windows certificate store and select the certificate is described in the previous procedure." I installed my X509Certificate in the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store. Wouldn't that be a Windows certificate store? Because nothing shows up in the Certificate Store window.

Searching online resources didn't yield much either unless I am using the wrong combination of keywords. Now I could create another X509Certificate and key ensuring that the extension of the key is .pfx but I wanted to make certain that I am on the right course of resolve before spinning my wheels for nothing and I don't believe that would be the answer.

So, can a .NET assembly be signed using an X509Certificate? If so, what documentation is available to assist in performing this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is what you want to do. There exist .NET signing (using RSA keypair) used for strong-naming the assemblies, and there exists Authenticode which lets you sign any file in PE format including assemblies in DLL files. Note, that Authenticode is not .NET-specific and knows nothing about .NET. It signs PE structure.

As said by poupou, for Authenticode signing (using X.509 certificates suitable for Code Signing) you can use SignTool.exe tool. .NET will verify the signature when it loads the assembly, but in some cases such verification can take extra seconds (if the OS performs CRL and OCSP checking of certificates in the chain), slowing down assembly loading.

So you need to choose the right tool and define what you want to achieve (signing is a method, not a goal).

Comment: Eugene, thank you for the additional information. Performance is most definitely a consideration that will be relevant to what I am doing down the line. But for now, I am just attempting to get a more solid grasp on the entire authentication process using X509Certificates by emulation. However, knowing the implications are definitely relevant. Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

Publisher* classes are associated with Authenticode(tm).

Look for the command-line tools:
* signcode (or signtool)
* chktrust

for how you can sign any .exe, .dll (and .cab, .ocx) using a valid code-signing certificate. A google search on Authenticode or "code-signing certificate" can also be helpful.

Comment: Ok, so I will research more; this time for Authenticode and command line tools available to support signing assemblies. Thank you!